# Avoid password check for read of a single file (Apache + dav_svn)

Tags: apache-2.2, svn

I've got a Subversion repository of private files, served by Apache over HTTPS using **dav_svn**. I'd like to give users in a single domain read access to a single file from this repository using HTTP. How do I write such an override? The current configuration:

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /var/lib/svn

  AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.authz
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
  Require valid-user
</Location>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears an old one, but it popped up in the RSS feed, so..

If I've understood the question correctly, you want to override the authentication for one file only.

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /var/lib/svn

  AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.authz
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
  Require valid-user
</Location>

<Files /path/to/file>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /var/lib/svn

  AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.authz
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd

  Require valid-user
  Allow from .some.domain.com # A domain name (requires the slow hostname lookups)
  Allow from 192.168.10.0/24 # An IP subnet
  Satisfy any    
</Files>
```

As **katriel** said, using the Satisfy directive allows you to specify alternate permission. Using this in the Files directive restricts the overrides to specific files.
This won't allow commits as only one file has access without authentication. You can always make sure with a pre-commit or start-commit hook.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using both authentication and allow,deny based access control on the same directory. The using "Satisfy" you can "OR" them both. Using the authz file, you can allow read-only access on a certain path in the repository
It will look something like:

```
<Location /svn>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /var/lib/svn

  AuthzSVNAccessFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.authz
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Subversion Repository"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd

  Require valid-user
  Order Allow,Deny
  Allow from .some.domain.com
  Satisfy any

 </Location>
```

and in the authz file use

```
[repo:/public/dir]
* = r
@writers = rw
```

This is not a perfect solution, bur there's no real other  way to exclude a domain from authenticating

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a good idea to expose a repository to anonymous commits under any circumstance. You might want to try a more elaborate setup, using a post-commit hook to perform an update and exposing *that* directory through an alias with read-only access for a particular subnet or domain:

e.g. in /var/lib/svn/repos/hooks/post-commit :

```
#!/bin/sh
# Of course, the update directory should be checked out the first time
cd /var/www/repomirror
svn update
```

And in your httpd.conf

```
<Location /repomirror>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from apache.org 
</Location>
```

YMMV